# Local website do not work for everyone

Tags: web-server, web-hosting

We have got a website (hosted locally but available over the internet) that does not work for everybody. The problem has been reported by internal users having windows vista home. If they go on our website with this address http://example.com, everything is fine. If the address is http://www.example.com it doesn't work, they get a simple error message that suggest to reload the page. It's not all Vista users that have this problem.

For the rest of our group, both address are working. Our server (Windows Server 2008) accept both headers. Cache has been cleared and all browser get the same error on those vista home, so I don't know what to do more. Maybe it's a server security? Any ideas?

---

As suggested by @TheCleaner I did a ping to our website:

On Windows 7

```
I get a 209.161.xxx.xx for both website (It's the good address)
```

On Vista

```
I get a 208.69.xx.xxx for the website with www. (the 209.161.xxx.xx should be the good one...but I see my website)
I get a 192.168.1.25 without the www. (this was an old server that crashed about 2 month ago)
```

How do I resolve this? Thanks

Comment: Can these problematic clients ping "www.example.com"?  Do they get the same results as pinging example.com?

Comment: if ping is blocked, can they do an nslookup for each record and compare the results to ensure they are both resolvable and resolving to the same address.

Comment: In addition, what holds the internet facing IPs? Is it the server itself, or a network device such as a load balancer?

Comment: Vista *home*?  Really?  Sounds like the excuse you need to get rid of Vista home from your network.  Upgrade to a professional edition of a Windows desktop OS.

Comment: You can try to flush dns info first by opening cmd and doing "ipconfig /flushdns" then wait a few min. Other option worth a look is if the website is a IIS site. Check the website binding if it includes www. and without. This can be a dns problem many times.

Comment: flushing dns didn't resolve the issue. Yes it's an IIS server so I looked in the bindings and for the http - no hostname - All unassigned Address for IPAdress - Port 80         I already try adding manually the www. and without but it didn't changed anything for the vista users

Comment: @HopelessN00b By my own I would buy Windows 7 professional for everyone (I hate Vista) but if my boss can save 1$ for something (illegal or not), he will do it...

Comment: @Shadowizoo  You need to do a software inventory, report your boss to the BSA for his illegal activities (using the software inventory as proof), and use the reward money to live off of while you find a new job.  Seriously.

Comment: @HopelessN00b For personal reason, I need to keep my job (at least 6 more month) and then I'll quit for sure. Don't worry, I will call everything I know :) Sorry to not elaborate more, but this is kind of off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are any/all of these clients connected via a proxy, or do they access the server directly? It sounds like there's some legacy stuff hanging around. Can you check the C:/Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts file to see if the server has some nasty hard coded stuff in there?

Comment: You hit directly the problem. There was junk (over 500 of website junk) Thanks !!!!